# Make CSS changes responsive and prevent line break

Tags: css, responsive-design

I want to make the Title text that displays on my homepage larger and prevent it from breaking to a second line…

The following CSS code works, but then it no longer displays properly on mobile devices…

How can I implement the CSS changes below so they will also be properly responsive? (I really only want these changes for full-sized computer monitors anyhow…I’m happy with the orig default settings for mobile.
Thank you.

```
.home .welcome-message .wrap {width: 1240px;}
.home .welcome-message h1{font-size: 3.6em;}
```

http://ifear.me/ password:**welcome**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

White-space: nowrap is what you need for preventing breaking the line.
Media-queries will allow you to add custom css for windows with different widths.

```
.home .welcome-message .wrap { width: 1240px; }
.home .welcome-message h1 { font-size: 3.6em; }

@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .home .welcome-message h1 {
    font-size: 12.6em; 
    white-space: nowrap 
  }
}
```

Example here: [fiddlejs](http://jsfiddle.net/adkm8t6L/)

Answer (score 1):

In responsive scenario you need to care about 2 things. one is the size of the display in pixel, for example 1920*1080 etc. and the second is pixel ratio that means the density of pixel per area(per inch in most of scenario). thus you should have various CSS file/classes those separated by media and aspect ratio and load the proper one in each display.

These two CSS link for 2 type of media first is 1024px width display with lce/led normal pixel ratio and second for a sample mobile device display with 768px pixel width and 1.5 pixel ratio:

```
<link href="~/css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width : 1024px) and (max-width : 1920px)"/>

<link href="~/css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width : 768px) and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5)"/>
```

Some useful link are below:

- http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/responsivedesign/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Hope this help.